# Make typescript warn when accessing a record values using a variable

Tags: typescript

For some reason typescript is not warning me that certain property can be potentially undefined when I'm accessing a dynamic record with a variable. It is IMO too naive to think that a record can contain all the strings in existence. For me, the below code should ideally error because el is undefined, but typescript just ignores that:

```
type Score = Record<string, number>

const people: Score = {
  danielo: 11,
  madro: 33
}
// Ok
const someone = people.danielo

let x = 'madre'

const el = people[x]
const shouldError = el + 2
```

This works properly on flow and I want the same behaviour on Ts. Having this could have saved me from some errors on production code.
I already have noImplicitAny activated, so it is not that my compiler options are too vague.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=true#code/FAFwngDgpgBAygYwPYCdYF4YCUrJQEwB4BnEFASwDsBzAGhkoFcBbAIyhQD5hhlLSY0JBAA2UAFzw8GGAG9gMGPgCGlclBFJJARm20FMZsvwotMAMzngAX2AB6OzADyAa15J%20IGMSTMoHmSFRKAA6FTUNJB4xLwAPGEwAciMTKESePgENBMF-YIBtWIBdd09vAAskRhF8AFEUUxQc7IBqGAAmIA)

**-- EDIT --**

I see that my question was not concrete enough, so I will try to narrow it down a bit.
I'm using an exported interface from react-redux-firebase. [They provide some TS typings to help you get type safety on your reducers](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/getting_started.html#add-reducer-using-typescript). However, because how they are defined they don't warn against what the original question was trying to state.

They reducer interface is defined as this:

```
export namespace FirebaseReducer {
  export interface Reducer<
    ProfileType extends Record<string, any> = {},
    Schema extends Record<string, any> = {}
    > {
    auth: AuthState
    profile: Profile<ProfileType>
    authError: any
    data: { [T in keyof Schema]: Record<string, Schema[T]> }
    ordered: {
      [T in keyof Schema]: Array<{ key: string; value: Schema[T] }>
    }
    errors: any[]
    isInitializing: boolean
    listeners: Listeners
    requested: Dictionary<boolean>
    requesting: Dictionary<boolean>
    timestamps: Dictionary<number>
  }
```

So when you use it, you do it like this:

```
interface Schema {
  names: Name;
}

// with both reducer types
export interface RootState {
  firebase: FirebaseReducer.Reducer<Profile, Schema>;
}
```

If it is possible to get the type safety I'm looking for changing any of my definitions before passing it down to the interface, I will love to.
But if that is not possible, I have already forked the library to provide some new features, so I will not mind fixing also some typings.

Comment: This is because of `type Score = Record<string, number>`
It explicitly states that "any string can be used as index of type Score and will get number value". If you want to have it strongly typed, you should narrow the index type to e.g. enum

Comment: I can't narrow it to an enum because it is data coming from the backend and can include any string. I just want to say that some strings may not exist on the record. I can't change the record definition either because I'm using an external library. If you have any suggestion I may consider forking the library

Comment: What are "some strings"? Do you know them?
Maybe optional props are the way to go?
It's hard to advice if I do not see your full case.

Comment: You need type Score = Record<string, number | undefined> or type Score = Partial<Record<string, number>> (two ways of writing the same thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Record access is inherently unsafe in Typescript because a type like `Record<string, number>` says that ANY string key will return a number value, so you need to be careful of this.

You can always define a function to help you like this:

```
type Score = Record<string, number>

const safeLookup = <Key extends string>(key: Key) =>
  <T extends Record<string, unknown>>(record: T): T[Key] | undefined => record[key]

const people: Score = {
  danielo: 11,
  madro: 33
}
// Ok
const someone = people.danielo

let x = 'madre'

const el = safeLookup(x)(people)
const shouldError = el + 2 // Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

Libraries like `fp-ts` have this built-in: https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Record.ts.html#lookup

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that may be a valid workaround, albeit it introduces a small performance hit and you need to remember to use it because you have to remember that types are wrong. I updated my original question to clarify my situation a bit, if you want to take a look and propose something.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your question with more details. It's odd that they use `data: { [T in keyof Schema]: Record<string, Schema[T]> }` in the type rather than just `data: Schema`